# Inserting a row with SQL Server Management Studio results in ERROR

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is what I have

```
CREATE TABLE  Saver( 
    SaverID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(10),
        Surname VARCHAR(10),
    [Address] VARCHAR(60),
    Email VARCHAR(30),
    Username VARCHAR(10),
    [Password] VARCHAR(10), 
    CreditBalance INT,
);
```

I'm trying to insert data into my table with this:

```
INSERT INTO Customer
 (SaverID,FirstName,Surname,[Address],Email,Username,[Password],CreditBalance)
  VALUES (01,'David','Slavic','123 fake street','David@gmail.com','DJ','passcode',10.00);
```

I get this error:

> Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Customer' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I don't understand why? Please help

Answer (score 3):

You should not insert value for  SaverID, you have told the RDBMS to generate a value for it (you've done so with your CREATE statement): `SaverID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY`.

Answer (score 0):

Your primary key is auto increment, you can not insert a value on it

Answer (score 0):

Omit the ID from your INSERT query:

```
INSERT INTO Customer
 (FirstName,Surname,[Address],Email,Username,[Password],CreditBalance)
  VALUES ('David','Slavic','123 fake street','David@gmail.com','DJ','passcode',10.00);
```